# Frequency Distribution and Probability for dependent events

Tags: probability

You are playing 3 lacrosse games this week.  One game will be on grass and 2 will be on turf; 2 at home and 1 away. Calculate a frequency distribution for the probability of winning at least two of these games.

I know I am supposed to write the different types of occurances, but I don't understand why whether or not playing grass or turf, home or away will matter?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will, maybe it won't - that doesn't mean you can't answer the question (it also doesn't make any sense because "grass" and "turf" are synonyms - what the hey!).

Here are the events:
$$G - \text{play on grass}$$
$$H - \text{play at home}$$

Given the data there are only 2 possible ways of playing, $A=\{G\cup H,G\cup H,G'\cup H'\}$ or $A'=\{G\cup H,G\cup H',G'\cup H\}$. From what you have said there is no way of determining how likely either is. Again, doesn't matter we can still answer the question.

So we can assign probabilities of winning:

$$P(G|H)$$
$$P(G'|H')$$
$$P(G|H')$$
$$P(G'|H)$$

And, probability of the draw:

$$P(A)$$

I will give you the answer for winning all 3 games - you can do the more horrible part of winning just 2.

$$P(A)\left[2P(G|H)+P(G'|H')\right]+(1-P(A))\left[P(G|H)+P(G|H')+P(G'|H)\right]$$

Comment: Not at all a mathematical comment, but 'turf' is often used in place of 'artificial turf'.

Comment: To be really technical, "grass" is the actual vegetable matter, "turf" is the grass plus the topsoil that supports the root system - such precision, while admirable in mathematics, is just needless pedantry in English.

Comment: Sorry. I thought you were just confused as to why you would differentiate the two. I'm just pointing out that in sports jargon the two words often refer to different things. So, there is a context where using them differently 'makes sense'.